# kubernetes hpa cannot get cpu consumption

Tags: docker, kubernetes, autoscaling

I am trying to configure kubernetes horizontal pod autoscaling. The definition of my deployment is [here](http://pastebin.com/bPG1hF2a).

I start heapster deployment and heapster service like below:

```
# kubectl run heapster --namespace=kube-system --image=gcr.io/google_containers/heapster:v1.0.2 --command -- /heapster --source=kubernetes:http://192.168.122.159:8080?inClusterConfig=false --sink=log
# kubectl expose deployment heapster --port=80 --target-port=8082 --name=heapster --namespace=kube-system
```

The hpa is create like this:

```
# kubectl autoscale deployment nginx-rc --max=5 --cpu-percent=25
```

The heapster seems to run fine. Here are the [logs](http://pastebin.com/k2dzgnQJ).

After all this, the hpa is not receiving any data on CPU utilization.

```
# kubectl describe hpa
Name:               nginx-rc
Namespace:          default
Labels:             <none>
Annotations:            <none>
CreationTimestamp:      Sat, 04 Jun 2016 07:23:03 -0400
Reference:          Deployment/nginx-rc/scale
Target CPU utilization:     25%
Current CPU utilization:    <unset>
Min replicas:           1
Max replicas:           5
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From                SubobjectPath   Type        Reason          Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----                -------------   --------    ------          -------
  9m        7s      22  {horizontal-pod-autoscaler }            Warning     FailedGetMetrics    failed to get CPU consumption and request: metrics obtained for 0/1 of pods
  9m        7s      22  {horizontal-pod-autoscaler }            Warning     FailedComputeReplicas   failed to get CPU utilization: failed to get CPU consumption and request: metrics obtained for 0/1 of pods
```

Controller manager logs have a recurring line:

```
Jun 04 07:21:33 master kube-controller-manager[8202]: W0604 07:21:33.079677    8202 horizontal.go:108] Failed to reconcile nginx-rc: failed to compute desired number of replicas based on CPU utilization for Deployment/default/nginx-rc: failed to get CPU utilization: failed to get CPU consumption and request: metrics obtained for 0/1 of pods
```

Can someone point out the nature of the problem here?

Comment: I have the same problem and I'm looking for a solution for two days. Have you set up the DNS server?

Comment: no. why is DNS server required here?

Comment: if you `describe` heapster rc, you can see that it set http:kubernetes.default. In my case, it was there the error

Comment: heapster is a deployment, not rc. Here is what describe shows me:
```
Name:   heapster
Namespace:  kube-system
CreationTimestamp: Sat, 04 Jun 2016 07:11:31 -0400
Labels:   run=heapster
Selector:  run=heapster
Replicas:  1 updated | 1 total | 1 available | 0 unavailable
StrategyType:  RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds: 0
RollingUpdateStrategy: 1 max unavailable, 1 max surge
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:  heapster-3915811212 (1/1 replicas created)
No events.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the problem is that you're not running DNS in your cluster.

HPA currently uses heapster service name to read metrics. You have properly created it, but HPA controller cannot resolve service name to IP address as there's not DNS in your cluster.

I have create issue https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/27044 to have more informative events that would help the user/admin understand the problem better.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is because you're not running a heapster service. The metrics client for the HorizontalPodAutoscaler attempts to get the metrics from a service named `heapster` in the `kube-system` namespace. You can look at the default Heapster definition [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/release-1.2/cluster/addons/cluster-monitoring).

If that's not the issue, look for `/var/log/kube-controller-manager` on the master node. In particular, look for entries with `failed to get pods metrics`.

Comment: I have written both the things above. `kubectl expose` creates the service and endpoint. The log line from controller-manager is posted in the question as well.